# Best free Talend learning resource?

Tags: data, talend

Does anyone have any recommendations for Talend tutorials/training? Specifically I am looking for Salesforce data integration/updates if possible. I am completely new to the tool.

Comment: I am experienced with SFDC. I am looking specifically for talend info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a search online and these all look like good resources:

http://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-salesforce-reference.html
https://www.talend.com/resources/podcast-videocast/integrating-with-salesforce
https://appirio.com/tech-blog/using-talend-to-export-data-from-salesforce-com
http://thirdsectorit.org/blog/migrating-data-from-sql-server-to-salesforce-com-using-talend-part-1/
http://www.datalytyx.com/automating-salesforce-routine-tasks-with-talend-open-studio/
https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=22179

Comment: There are great, thanks. I also searched but did not come across a few key ones there. Best regards